# ksqlDB recommendations for deploying large set of queries

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am running a ksqlDB streaming application that consists of a large number of queries (>60 queries), including many joins and aggregations. My data comes from various sources, and requires plenty of manipulation to produce the desired processed data, hence the large number of queries. I've run this set of queries on a single machine, using interactive mode, and it produces the right results. But I observe an increasing consumer lag when I increase the amount of data fed into the application.

I read on ksqlDB's [Capacity Planning](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/capacity-planning/) page that I can scale by adding more servers, which is what I plan to do.

Under [Important Sizing Factors](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/capacity-planning/#important-sizing-factors), it's also stated that *"You should avoid running a large number of queries on one ksqlDB cluster. Instead, use interactive mode to play with your data and develop sets of queries that function together. Then, run these in their own headless cluster."* However, I am unsure how to do this- my queries are all dependent on each other.

Does anyone have any general recommendations on how to deploy a large number of interdependent ksql queries? As an added requirement, the data is refreshed each day and is independent for the each new day, so I need to do some sort of refresh of the queries each day.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's just a recommendation if you can group queries that depend each other, and then split those groups into headless mode servers.

Another way, if you use interactive mode, is to partitioned your topics and add more ksql servers to your cluster. This will allow ksql to split the workload across the cluster, each server consuming and processing one partition. Say you have 4 partitions per topic and 2 servers, then you'll have 1 server processing 2 partitions and another server other 2 partitions. This should decrease the workload on each server.

Another improvement is to reduce the number of streams threads. Each query you create runs with 4 kafka streams threads by default. The more number of threads, the more parallel work is done in the server. With a large number of queries, performance decreases and lag is incremented. Try with 1 thread and see if that works. Set `ksql.streams.num.stream.threads=1` in the ksql-server.properties to configure it.